# Long Memory Tests - Gaussian Semiparametric (GSP) Method implementation in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to do some long memory tests for my financial data. I have read few articles explaining some of the tests such as GPH,Lo's modified R/S test and GSP test. below is the explanation of the model. Although i am not so sure if I am implementing it right.

[image]

[image]

what I did as a code is;

```
rt <- data_Timeseries
T <- length(rt)
# Number of frequencies to use
m <- floor(T/2)
# Calculate the Fourier frequencies
w <- 2 * pi * (1:m) / T
# Calculate the periodogram
I_w <- (1 / (2 * pi * T)) * abs(fft(rt)[1:m])^2
    
R_H <- function(H) {
first_term <- mean(I_w / w^(1 - 2 * H))
second_term <- (2 * H - 1) * mean(log(w))
return(log(first_term) - second_term)
}
H_hat <- optimize(R_H, interval = c(0.5, 1), tol = 1e-8)
    
# The optimize function returns a list, where the minimum is $minimum
H_estimate <- H_hat$minimum

I am trying to find:
d(α=0.45)
d(α=0.50) 
d(α=0.55) and their respective standard deviations of the estimates.
```

If anyone could guide me it will be appreciated.